# preventing checkout when clicking on Edit page

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, check-out

How to prevent a publishing page to be checked out when you click on Edit Page button. You have not done any changes yet, so no need to checkout the page.

Comment: do you want to keep the checkout but disable only on the first instance?

Comment: When ever you click on Edit Page it will be checked out. I want to keep it checked in until you change something.